# How to fetch dynamic url from a webpage div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to extract a dynamic url from a webpage. The url keeps changing, is there a way I could always have my app load after reading the url from the webpage?

```
//webpage
    <div style="display:none" id="urladdress">
        //dynamic url
        **https://freeuk30.listen2myradio.com/live.mp3?typeportmount=s1_13713_stream_467412061**        
   </div>
<div style="display:none" id="stream_type">audio</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No. When your app is in background the operating system gonna terminate the app after an unknown time.
2. You cannot execute background infinitely

I think you have to solve this issue with an own Webservice which is polling the mentioned site. After your service recognize changes you need to send push notifications which can trigger a background task for a short time.